# Accessing the number of an incoming call on iPhone

Tags: iphone, jailbreak

Assuming a jailbroken iPhone, how can I discover the number of an incoming call programmatically? And how can I access the call logs?

Answer (score 1):

There is quite a good post about file locations on the jailbroken device at this page: http://www.ihackintosh.com/2009/07/manually-backup-iphone-contacts-sms/

They use it as backup but I assume you can easily use SQLite to get content from it.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following observer to find the incoming call event:

```
id ct = CTTelephonyCenterGetDefault();
CTTelephonyCenterAddObserver(ct, NULL, callback, NULL, NULL, CFNotificationSuspensionBehaviorHold);
```

and then base on the type: `kCTCallStatusChangeNotification`
and using this function `CTCallCopyAddress` you will be able to get the caller ID.